# XPATH query to find attributes that contains a keyword

Tags: .net, xpath, attributes, contains

I'm trying to search something in multiple attributes in multiple different nodes

This is how I find it in one attribute

```
//*[contains(@name,'KEYA')]
```

Sample XML:

```
<cars>

<car model="2000" name="Awesome KEYA Car" name2="somethine else">Brand1</car>
<car model="2005" name="Awesome Car" name2="KEYA something else">Brand 2</car>
<car name="Awesome Car" name2="somethine else">Brand1</car>
<car dontmatch="KEYA" name2="somethine else">Brand3333</car>

</cars>
```

What I really want is something like this for more than 10 attributes (it needs to match only white-listed attributes),

```
//*[contains((@name or @name2 or @name3),'KEYA')]
```

Using XPATH 1.0. Any ideas about how to do this? Tried several ways other than repeating contains but didn't work.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy one-liner XPath expression solution, that gives you the flexibility to specify easily and in most compact and natural form the names of the attributes to be searched. Explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[@*
        [contains('|name|name1|name2|name3|name4|',
                  concat('|',name(),'|')
                  )
       and
         contains(., 'KEYA')
        ]
       ]
```

**Here is the selection, as produced by [the XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**:

[image]

**Explanation**:

**You can specify in a string the names of all attributes you want searched**. The "pipe delimiter (`|`)  used guarantees that even if a name is the start of another, it one will only be included in the search if there is a separate, pipe-delimited substring for this name.

Comment: Nice one, marked this as complete and thx for the explanation.

Comment: Is there any difference between `/*/*` and `//*` ?

Comment: @dr. evil: Yes, `/*/*` selects all elements that are children of the top element of the XML document, while `//*` selects all elements in the document.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
/cars/car/@*[contains(.,'KEYA')]/parent::*
```

[image]

ok, after the edit, then I suggest

```
/cars/car/@*[name()!='dontmatch'][contains(.,'KEYA')]/parent::*
```

[image]

If you want to exclude more than just one attribute, then you need to specify additional predicates (the things inside the square brackets).  Xpath doesn't provide a way to exclude sets of attr names, unless you can constrain the set with a `startswith()` or `contains()` or something similar.

There are handy ways to query XML in other libraries, like, for example LINQ-to-XML if you are using .NET.  That would allow you to specify those kinds of queries more succintly. But it's a different API altogether.

Comment: It needs to find only in certain list of attributes not all of them

Comment: Re: "Xpath doesn't provide a way ...". C'mon, why are you so sure? :) Other solutions prove this statement wrong. Not even to speak of XPath 2.0. As for the so called "XPath visualizer", I wonder when it will gain all the features of my own, much older, identically named tool -- or is this just my wishful thinking?

Comment: Dimitre, give it a rest. Please. Every comment you make on one of my answers or posts, is hostile, confrontational, or critical. There is no need for this. I don't know why you have such personal animosity towards me. There is no reason. Please stop. I'm sorry for re-using the name of the tool you built. It was not intended as an insult. Please relax.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
//*[contains(@name,'KEYA') or contains(@name2,'KEYA')]
```

You could take Cheeso's answer and do something like this:

```
/cars/car/@*[contains(.,'KEYA') and local-name() != 'dontmatch']/parent::*
```

One way or another you're going to have to construct the XPath statement to either select from a whitelist of attributes (my example), or exclude attributes in a blacklist (the modified Cheeso example).

Building again off of Cheeso's work this might simplify building the blacklist:

```
//@*[contains(.,'KEYA') and not(contains('dontmatch,dontmatch2', local-name()))]/parent::*
```

or as a whitelist:

```
//@*[contains(.,'KEYA') and contains('name,name2', local-name())]/parent::**
```

Comment: Yeah that will solve the problem but it'll be really ugly to manage :)

Comment: @dr. evil - I probably agree, @cheeso's solution is better if you're searching **all** of the attributes.

Comment: @Kev I'm not searching for all though

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to find something like this "contains((@name or @name2 or @name3),'KEYA')" but I guess I have to whitelist stuff with so many contains

Comment: @dr. evil - see my latest update, it might simplify constructing a white/black list

Comment: What's /parent::** for? I'm using XPATH visualizer and it works without the /parent bit

Comment: I like it but I guess it's a bad hack and might cause unexpected bugs, i.e. this will return incorrect results "//@*[contains(.,'KEYA') and contains('name2', local-name())]"

Comment: @dr. evil without the `/parent::*` you'd just be selecting the attribute nodes, `/parent::*` selects the parent XML node containing the attributes

Comment: @dr. evil - yeah it's not ideal if your attribute names are similar.